# Shape with striped background and a triangular cut on top

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

Hello I need to make shape in CSS/HTML5. I pasted it as an image but now I need to make shape like this.

Is there any way to do it? I made something with triangles but it doesn't even look close to this.

SHAPE: [image]

Here is my CSS.

```
#flag {
  width: 110px;
  height: 56px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative; 
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
    float:left;
}
#flag:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid #eee;
  border-left: 55px solid transparent;
  border-right: 55px solid transparent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="flag"></div><span>SOME TEXT HERE</span>
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k2ywe9j9/)

Comment: Are the dimensions (height & width) of your flag fixed? If yes, does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/k2ywe9j9/1/) meet your needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using either of the following 2 options.

**Option 1:** Using box-shadow and an extra pseudo-element.

In this option an extra pseudo-element of size 20px is added (white/grey color) and using appropriately positioned box-shadows, the striped pattern is achieved. This method can be useful if the dimensions of your flag element is fixed.

```css
#flag {
  width: 110px;
  height: 56px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#flag:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid #eee;
  border-left: 55px solid transparent;
  border-right: 55px solid transparent;
}
#flag:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -30px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #eee;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-shadow: -20px 60px 0px #eee, -20px 80px 0px #eee, -20px 20px 0px #eee, -20px -20px 0px #eee, 0px 40px 0px #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="flag"></div><span>SOME TEXT HERE</span>
```

---

**Option 2**: Using Linear Gradients

In this method the stripes are obtained using linear-gradients as a background on a pseudo-element which is rotated by 45 degrees to achieve the diagonal stripes effect. This option can be used even if the dimensions are not fixed because of usage of percentage for linear-gradients.

```css
div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%, #eee 50%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, red 50%, #eee 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, red 50%, #eee 50%);
    background-size: 100% 20px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 150%;
    width: 150%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 15% 60%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 15% 60%;
    transform-origin: 15% 60%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
div:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #eee;
    top: -25%;
    left: 25%;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Note:** In the second sample, I had positioned the top triangle such that it still leaves some space on either sides just for an example. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpskh0uh/1/) has a top triangle that covers the full width of the flag.

Comment: Just added the prefixed and standard versions @dippas. Noticed that it is still having troubles, checking on it.

Comment: @dippas: It should work now in FF mate. I always goof up with the difference in angles between the Webkit and standard versions :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use css gradients for this, as well as a single pseudo element:

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 41%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 55%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 55%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 61%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 76%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 81%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 95%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 96%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(15%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(15%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(15%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(16%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(16%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(20%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(20%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(21%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(35%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(35%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(41%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(55%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(55%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(60%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(61%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(75%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(75%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(76%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(80%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(81%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(95%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(96%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 15%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 41%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 61%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 76%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 81%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 95%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 96%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 15%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 41%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 61%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 76%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 81%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 95%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 96%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 15%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 41%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 61%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 76%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 81%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 95%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 96%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 15%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 41%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 61%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 76%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 81%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 95%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 96%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */

  }
div:before{
  content:"";
position:absolute;
  border-top:150px solid white;
  border-left:150px solid transparent;
  border-right:150px solid transparent;
  top:0;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

A slightly different approach to create the upper section would also be ok (i guess):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 21%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 41%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 81%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 95%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 96%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(21%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(35%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(41%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(55%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(81%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(95%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(96%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 21%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 41%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 81%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 95%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 96%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 21%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 41%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 81%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 95%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 96%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 21%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 41%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 81%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 95%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 96%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 21%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 41%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 81%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 95%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 96%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: white;
  top: 0;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Useful resource:** [Gradient editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)